# Haar prior for von Mises distribution

Tags: distributions, self-study, bayesian, prior, circular-statistics

Ok, Let me tell you that this is the very first time that I have no idea with the question below. I can not find a solution or anything that will lead me to it. I say this to prevent comments "what did you do?". I apologize in advance.

This is one of the questions in Peter M. Lee's Bayesian Statistics: An Introduction book, it is Exercises section of Chapter 3.

How can I find a Haar prior for a location parameter on the circle (such as $\mu$ in the case of von Mises's distribution).

Comment: Hint: By definition, a [Haar measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure) is invariant under the action of a group on itself. What group would you (naturally) associate with the circle? What would it mean, geometrically, for a measure to be unchanged under that group action?